# Change a MySQL password without logging

Tags: mysql

I'd like to change my MySQL password but don't want my new password written to my MySQL log file.  Is it possible to instruct MySQL not to log the next command entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new password will never be written in the log it would be a huge breach of security.

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-logging.html) :
Statement logging avoids writing passwords in cleartext for the following statements:

```
CREATE USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ...
GRANT ... IDENTIFIED BY ...
SET PASSWORD ...
SLAVE START ... PASSWORD = ...
CREATE SERVER ... OPTIONS(... PASSWORD ...)
ALTER SERVER ... OPTIONS(... PASSWORD ...)
```

Passwords in those statements are rewritten to not appear literally in statement text written to the general query log.

**But** if the password is written in clear it means that server is started with `--log-raw` option :

> For the general query log, password rewriting can be suppressed by
>   starting the server with the `--log-raw` option. For security reasons,
>   this option is not recommended for production use. For diagnostic
>   purposes, it may be useful to see the exact text of statements as
>   received by the server.